# How do I install minecraft Forge?

Tags: games

I've downloaded minecraft via the PPA & want to use mods, the only mods I can find need Forge to run, on Microsoft doing so is easy, anyone know how to on Linux? (I prefer to do it via terminal) (I'll add info or change info as I get responses) (I'm technically using lubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out after asking.

I started out by going to: https://files.minecraftforge.net/

then I downloaded it to the desktop (I used 1.10 version, but that doesn't really matter)

then i used then commands in this order

```
$ cd Desktop
$ java -jar jarfilename.jar
```

And now it's modded. .;,;. (I used the command to launch the jar file due to me not being able to do so any other way on my computer).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this one is easy:

go to 'http://files.minecraftforge.net/' and select the forge version you need to use and download either the sources or the universal jar file. For this answer I assume you used the jarfile.

now `cp /path/to/downloaded.jar /path/to/minecraft/mods/<filename>.jar`

start minecraft, it should be modded now and you can copy other mods into your mods directory you want ot use.

Comment: is this a command, (ie terminal) or not, if not what does this even mean, i'm somewhat of a beginner to terminal, anyway, I've already figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole other way. You could used [Multi MC](http://multimc.org) . This approach is especially usefull if you want to keep multible differnet modpack around to play with.

You can download the deb package for Ubunutu and install with `dpkg`.
to install forge and other mods, you start multmc create a instance and edit the instance.